# Pre-Load-Table in JAX-RS in JBoss

Tags: java, rest, caching, jboss, jax-rs

I want to pre-load a small table (300 rows) in a Java datastructure (List, HashMap,..) when my application server starts. I am using a JBoss Application Server which has a JAX-RS service deployed.

Where can I find documentation how to do this? I've tried to search the web but probably don't have the right keywords :(

Or is there any special method that is run in a JAX-RS webservice which can save all the data? (e.g. can I just write a loadData()-method in my *Application-Class and reference the datastructure from other classes?)